# How to Disable Save and Save As using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro and I need to disable the save function on the workbook that VBA has copied and pasted all the information into. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `Application` object to access the toolbar buttons directly:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Save As...").Enabled = False 
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("File").Controls("Save").Enabled = False 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 63):

You can use the Workbook_BeforeSave event to achieve this, disabling the CommandBars won't stop your users using a shortcut such as CTRL + S.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox "You can't save this workbook!"
    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to note that the proposal by Francis must be saved in VBA in design mode because this piece of code works so perfect that it doesn`t allow to save itself :-)

Comment: This is the more appropriate answer.

Comment: This is more reliable than using the answer marked as answer.

Comment: How do you save this code, once it in place. Because if you click save it is cancelled

Comment: Neither this nor the accepted answers do work for my Excel 2010 WinXP 32bit :(

Comment: I don't know why but my Office 2010 ignores Cancel = True and accepts Cancel = 1

Comment: @TomHanson too late, but as user2249468 mentioned, you can go to Design Mode and save it http://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/where-is-design-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

One more side note; I had difficulties with the above codes because my organization uses HUNGARIAN version of Excel.
So in case you use NON ENGLISH EXCEL you must specify the Controls elements in your Excel's local language ... in my case what worked was:

`Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Fá&jl").Controls("Menté&s má&ské&nt...").Enabled = False
Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Fá&jl").Controls("Menté&s").Enabled = False`