# How to disable Access 2007 save and save as completely

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, sharepoint, ms-office

I have an access 2007 document I will be sharing on a SharePoint site. My users will open it only in read-only format so that they can just query from it but make no changes to the database.

The problem is that looking at a security perspective, users can save the file natively and then have a look at the internal data as well as make changes to the database. This is possible because they can use a SAVE AS feature. So my question is : How to disable this feature so that they can not save it at all in any form.

Here is a link I found for Excel and it even worked in Excel but I cant do it in Access! 
Help is much appreciated :)

[How to Disable Save and Save As using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264572/how-to-disable-save-and-save-as-using-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to restrict, you can disable a few things in Access Options (depending on how restrictive you wish to be) and then compile the application to an ACCDE. Play around with disabling settings like Display Navigation Pane, Use Access Special Keys, Allow Full Menus and Allow Default Shortcut Menus. If you want you can hide the ribbon too. All depends on how restricted you want it. Then go to **File --> Save & Publish --> Make ACCDE**. The ACCDE file is a compiled version that restricts editing of the structure of the database including form designs, etc.

Comment: While I have tried all the things you mentioned so that nothing but the form will be visible to user, the problem is Access 2007 seems to not have save & publish - make accde format or I am missing it somewhere. I just don't want them to save a copy of the database for themselves. What I could try is that restrict all their access to the backend and then disable the Shift+Enter to open database such that even if they save it to their PC they wont be able to edit or look at anything.

Comment: In Access 2007, look in the Database Tools area on the ribbon. You should see a make ACCDE button.

Comment: @YusufN. The ACCDE instructions I gave originally were for an Access 2010 installation. My comment about the Database Tools area is for Access 2007 installations.

Comment: Yes, Found it. It sure is a good tool. The ACCDE restricts users from doing anything with the form design, reports and code. So as I see it, the ACCDE is the best for creating front end databases with all my forms and reports. This database can be linked to my database which has all the data. Give access to user to only this form database and disable all the stuff using which the user can see my backend, including disabling shift+enter mechanism. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: @YusufN. Exactly. Keeping them out of the VBA is important. ACCDE does everything you said. And yes they could boycott all the earlier restrictions with a Shift+Enter while opening the database. ACCDE is what really locks the file down.