# Macro to don't allow the user to save the document as another file format

Tags: vba, save, ms-word

I'm trying to build a macro that won't let the user save a copy of the document locally, but instead upload it to the server.

So far I was able to to it for the "save" and "save as" actions.

But, when the user "save as another file format" my macros don't prevent it.

The macros that I currently have, concerning to the events of saving, are:

```
Sub FileSave()
    SalvarDocumentoSePermitido 'our method to upload the document back to the server
End Sub

Sub FileSaveAs()
    SalvarDocumentoSePermitido 'our method to upload the document back to the server
End Sub
```

How can I intercept this event of saving as another file format?

Comment: Can you show what code is in "SalvarDocumentoSePermitido"?  The "FileSave" and "FileSaveAs" will fire depending on the option selected. That means your code is not detecting what they are doing.

Comment: Actually I've evolved my code a little bit. I have added these:

`Sub FileSaveAsOtherFormats()
    SalvarDocumentoSePermitido
End Sub

Sub FileSaveWordDocx()
    SalvarDocumentoSePermitido
End Sub

Sub FileSaveODT()
    SalvarDocumentoSePermitido
End Sub

Sub FileSaveWordDotx()
    SalvarDocumentoSePermitido
End Sub`

They intercept the "save as another format", "save as docx document", "save as a OpenDocument" and "save as a model".

It seems not very smart since there are many ways to save a document and it's pretty hard track'em all :-/

Comment: Did you forget to add the code?

Comment: I've edited it. It was a miss enter :-)

Comment: If I create ALL those event handlers, the 'FileSaveAs' always fires first, which would invoke your custom subroutine. Are you sure you can't trap within your subroutine? How are you able to get those other events to handle anything? I'm using Office 2010.

Comment: I'm using Office 2007. The "FileSaveAs" is only fired when the user clicks the "Save as" button. I have tested it on my side with a "MsgBox" inside the "FileSaveAs" right before mine subroutine and the message isn't displayed unless I click the "Save as" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate everyone's help, specially Lary's which gave me the insight to work with the "BeforeSave".
But my question has been answered by the guys from MSDN as you can see here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c0f231b2-6129-4ed7-bcc0-41f95bcc1864/macro-to-dont-allow-the-user-to-save-the-document-as-another-file-format?forum=worddev

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to this post from 2012:
[How to Disable Save and Save As using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264572/how-to-disable-save-and-save-as-using-vba)

In Excel, you need to turn on "Design mode" and insert this piece of code into Workbook Module and save it in VBA/Excel in "Design Mode" because this code is so powerful that you can't even save the new code iteslf.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    SalvarDocumentoSePermitido
    Cancel = True

End Sub
```