# How to prohibit user from using saveas in calc open office?

Tags: vba, macros, openoffice-calc

Been searching for some time now. I'm not very familiar with macro in calc than in VBA. I hope you can help me with the specific code on how to disable or prohibit saveas in any way. Actual codes will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] to post better questions.

Comment: @TDL, Please see if this is going to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264572/how-to-disable-save-and-save-as-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

It is not as easy with OpenOffice as it is with Excel.  You need to disable the dispatcher command as described at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/WritingUNO/Disable_Commands.

The command name is `SaveAs`.

Chapter 9 of [this PDF document](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/w/images/e/ef/AdministrationGuide_OOo3.1.0.pdf) gives more instructions for the `Commands.xcu` file.