# Workbook get saved despite the code savechanges=false

Tags: excel, savechanges, vba

I'm having a recurring problem. Even when my code has exclusively stated to not save changes, the workbook still gets saved on completion of program.

```
wb2.Close Savechanges = False
wb1.Close Savechanges = False
```

The problem is that when it has a later timestamp, someone might assume some changes were made, even though there weren't any.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. Thisworkbook.Saved = True fools excel into thinking the workbook has already been saved..

```
Sub Auto_Close()
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

Or alter your syntax to

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

Note the colon!

Comment: I will try the .saved trick. I am opening and closing a no. of workbooks and I have already tried appending  'Savechanges:= False' or just 'False' which is not working

Answer (score 0):

I like this answer provided by Francis Dean in a previous post on the same topic as it it actually informs the user that the wb won't be saved. However, for this solution to work, you need to save it inside the VBA Design mode.

Another great advantage of this solution is it even when the user use CTRL+S (without call any close event)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

[How to Disable Save and Save As using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264572/how-to-disable-save-and-save-as-using-vba)

Comment: This seems like a reasonable idea but I'm opening and closing a lot of workbooks, so the msgbox will probably annoy the user more than it will help.